# convert data grid view image to byte array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am working on vb.net windows application.
I have a picture in my 6th Cell of data grid view. I want to save that image in database.
So I write code like this:

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
Dim imgCon As New ImageConverter
ms.Read(imgCon.ConvertTo(gv.Rows(0).Cells(6).Value, GetType(Byte())), 0, 1024)
Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()
```

But here my image is not converting Byte array? How I can convert my data grid view image to byte array? Any help is very appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the image from the `DataGridView` and save the image into a memory stream. Write the stream content to byte array. My VB is little rusty so I have given the sample code in C#

Sample code:

```
Image image = myDGV.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value as Image;
if(image != null)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    byte[] imagedata = ms.ToArray();
}
```